# How to Find a String Between Specific Keyword and Double Quote

Tags: regex, string, vb.net, double-quotes

I have a line of string and I need to find the words after a specific keywords and double Quote Character.

Example:

The input string is 'Dim lsParameter as string = Parameters("**ThisValue**")'

The expected result is **ThisValue**

I need to save whatever string between keyword '**Parameters("**' and '**")**'. 
Any kind of clue is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Give an example of the your input string and Expected output ... would help more to understand

Comment: Are you doing this in C# or VB.NET? Your input string suggests you are doing VB.NET so why have you also tagged C#?

Answer (score 1):

```
\(\"(.*)\"\)
```

This regex will save into a capture group the text between `("` and `")`

Try it out [here](http://regexr.com/) with your text.

Let me know if this helps!